# How to open modal form on page load

Tags: 7, webforms, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I'm using [modal form](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) in drupal7.26 with WEBFORM module and is working fine when I click  a link the form opens in new modal.

What I want is to open the same WEBFORM with out clicking any link instead it should be open on page/body load event.

I'm using [modal form](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) with CTOOLS and WEBFORM modules.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
-Zafar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to automatically load a modal when the page is loaded, IMO that's a bad user experience. But if you must, you can use a bit of jQuery in the theme to make it happen. Maybe something like the following:

```
  /**
   * Open Modal window on page load.
   */
   Drupal.behaviors.openModalOnPageLoad = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // Just create some kind of ID or class for the modal link, add whatever extra
      // classes you need to be more specific if necessary.
      $(".page-node-number #myModalLink").click();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Might be best to use `Drupal.CTools.Modal.show()`.  I'm not certain that `click()` will work on every browser.